# Fluentmigrator migrate into specific version

Tags: fluent-migrator

Is there any possibility to migrate database changes to any specific version. As a example we have list of migration within out project and we want to migrate only version 2 changes into the database. I may have below migrations

- Version 1 - Already in DB
- Version 2 - **Want to migrate to the DB**
- Version 3 - Will migrate later.

  Is there any command like `migrate:up --Version 2`? I am using **FluentMigrator.1.4.0.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to do this using below script.

```
Migrate.exe /connection "data source=source;initial catalog=db;User ID=sa;Password=123;" /db SQLserver2012 /timeout 600 /task migrate:up --version=2 /target ..\DatabaseMigration\bin\Debug\DatabaseMigration.dll

pause
```

Comment: thanks for putting this here, exactly what i needed